# How to declare a template function with a std::ratio template parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to define three functions with C++14 as below:

```
template <typename D = std::chrono::seconds>
typename D::rep test() {
    // somethinig
}

template <std::intmax_t N, std::intmax_t D = 1, typename V = uint64_t>
V test() {
     // something
}
```

The two functions work as expected. I can call them like `test<std::chrono::minutes>()` and `test<60>`. Now, I want to define the third function, which accepts a `std::ratio` as a template parameter.

```
template <template<std::intmax_t, std::intmax_t> class R, std::intmax_t N, std::intmax_t D, typename V = uint64_t>
V test() {
    // R<N, D> should be std::ratio<N, D>
    // something
}
```

But in this case I would get a compile-time error while calling `test<std::milli>()`. I think it's because the compiler mixed up the first function and the third function. How could I define the third one?

Comment: 3rd function should be called like `test<std::ratio, 1, 1000>()`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes you are right. My problem is just right there: I didn't know how to define a template function with a `std::ratio` template parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define some traits to detect whether the type `T` is a specialization of `duration` or `ratio`:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <ratio>

template<class>
struct is_duration : std::false_type { };

template<class Rep, class Period>
struct is_duration<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>> : std::true_type { };

template<class>
struct is_ratio : std::false_type { };

template<std::intmax_t Num, std::intmax_t Denom>
struct is_ratio<std::ratio<Num, Denom>> : std::true_type { };
```

Then use `enable_if` to enable the corresponding function according to the type of `T`:

```
template<typename D = std::chrono::seconds, 
  std::enable_if_t<is_duration<D>::value>* = nullptr>
typename D::rep test() {
  // somethinig
}

template<typename R, typename V = uint64_t,
  std::enable_if_t<is_ratio<R>::value>* = nullptr> 
V test() {
  // R<N, D> should be std::ratio<N, D>
  // something
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/EfznTT713)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is tag dispatching:

```
template <typename> struct tag{};

template <typename Rep, typename Period> 
Rep test(tag<std::chrono::duration<Rep, Period>>)
{
    // ...
}

template <std::intmax_t Num, std::intmax_t Denom> 
uint64_t test(tag<std::chrono::ratio<Num, Denom>>)
{
    // ...
}

template <typename T> 
auto test() -> decltype(test(tag<T>{}))
{
    return test(tag<T>{});
}

template <std::intmax_t N, std::intmax_t D = 1, typename V = uint64_t>
V test() {
    // ...
}
```